# Transfer files with extended attributes: Redhat to Redhat

Tags: redhat, file-transfer, attributes

I need to transfer files with extended attributes from my local system (SL 6.5) to a remote server (Centos 5.6). However, both `scp` and `rsync` are dropping the attributes, so I'm having to manually `setfattr` on the server. Any pointers on how to do this properly? Thanks.

Comment: I have no centos 5.6 system handy, but on 6.5 you can use the -X, --xattrs for rsync and that should work. You can also use tar, it takes the attributes unless you specify not to take them with you with --no-xattrs

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AFAIK scp doesn't.

rsync has the `-X, --xattrs` switch for extended attributes (think SELinux contexts) and the `-A,  --acls` to preserve ACL's, which are what you modify with setfattr.

Comment: Side note - just tried this - `rsync -avX` preserves whatever was set by `setfattr`, even though `-a` doesn't include `-A`.